# CSS background-size fills parent

Tags: css

I have a div that I'd like to use a fixed background on. I'm also using background-size cover in order to get the best fit from the bg image.
The trouble is that the background image scales as if it were to cover the div's parent. Not the div itself. Is there any way to fix this?

```
.panel-image {
  height:100vh;
  width:50%;
  background-size:cover;
  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-position:center;
  background-image:my-image.jpg;
}

.parent{
  height:100vh;
}
```

Here is an online example. The panel-image div is square, as is the source image, yet the image is still heavily cropped as if panel-image div were much wider:

http://jsbin.com/siweloxebe/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Try adding display: inline-block; to .panel-image

Comment: Thanks, but still the same

Comment: Yes I am trying to get the image to comfortably cover the panel-image div with minimal cropping. It needs to be attachment fixed

Comment: its for a sort-of parallax effect yes

Answer (score 1):

It's because you've set the height of the child div the same as the parent.

I've played around with your code [here](http://jsbin.com/qepiyazunu/edit?html,css,output) and it seems fine, or I may have misunderstood your question

Comment: It still seems to act as if it has to cover the parent. If you look now, with a square panel-image div and a square image, the image should be virtually un-cropped, but it displays cropped as if the panel-image were the same width as the parent. http://jsbin.com/siweloxebe/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Oh yes, my bad. I took out ```background-attachment:fixed;``` and it seems to have been fixed. http://jsbin.com/josagusuvo/edit?html,css,output